# Как правильно и безопасно обращаться к переменным $_POST, $_SERVER и т.п

Tags: php

**IDE NetBeans** ругается, мол "не обращайтесь непосредственно к суперглобальному массиву **$_POST**".

Так вот вопрос, как правильно и безопасно обращаться к таким массивам и элементам этих массивов? Хорошо бы привести примерчик ;)

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть код, на который IDE у вас ругается

Comment: @sanmai, и код не нужен, речь за суперглобальные массивы. И то, что он напишет вам 1 строчку кода в виде `$_POST['name'];` вам ничего не даст, если вы понятия не имеете о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно работать через функцию [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php)

Для `POST`:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
```

Для `GET`:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name');
```

Поддерживаемые типы `INPUT_*`:
`INPUT_GET, 
INPUT_POST, 
INPUT_COOKIE, 
INPUT_SERVER или INPUT_ENV`.

Про фильтры, можно почитать [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.php)